# Parallel Structure in sentences

Tags: parallelism

I was given three incorrect sentences and the task is to correct them. I've googled many examples and explanations of parallel structure, but I'm still unsure whether my solutions are correct:

1. INCORRECT: "My boyfriend took me dancing and to a movie."
   MY SOLUTION: "My boyfriend took me to dance and a movie." OR "My
   boyfriend took me to a dance and a movie."
2. INCORRECT: "Climate change affects humans, the environment, and is scary."
   MY SOLUTION: "Climate change is scary, and it affects humans and the environment."
3. INCORRECT: "John Richards criticizes standardized tests because they are compulsory, funded by the government, and destroy students' humanity."
   MY SOLUTION: "John Richards criticizes standardized tests because they are compulsory, government-funded, and destroy students' humanity."

I hope you'll be able to help me and hopefully explain my mistakes.

Comment: Your solutions to #1 and #2 correct the problem, but #3 does not. You still have *are A, (are) B, and destroy C*.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Yes, a better answer might be "...and destructive of students' humanity." I still don't like it much but, if you take out the 'compulsory' and 'government funded' parts you still need 'are'. With '...and destroy..." you don't need the 'are' if you remove the other parts so it's not parallel. Mentally stripping out complexity can be useful when you are trying to answer questions like this. Another way to do it is to insert 'are' before 'funded by government' so that the word 'are' is not part of the parallel structures.